# Why does google.co.jp respond with 400 Bad Request?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, jenkins, open-uri

using build ruby program for jenkins

The content of the program is to access google

I have this title problem error

Here is mycode

```
file.each do |line|
    keyword = line.chomp
    base_url = 'http://www.google.com/complete/search?h1=ja&output=toolbar'
    url = "#{base_url}&q=#{keyword}"
    doc = REXML::Document.new(open(url).read.encode("UTF-8"))
    doc.elements.each('toplevel/CompleteSuggestion/suggestion') do |value|
```

If you want other code information, add it

Thank you

add

Post full error text

```
/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:377:in `open_http': 400 Bad Request (OpenURI::HTTPError)
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:755:in `buffer_open'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:226:in `block in open_loop'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `catch'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:165:in `open_uri'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:735:in `open'
    from /var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from suggest-word.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from suggest-word.rb:13:in `each'
    from suggest-word.rb:13:in `block in <main>'
    from suggest-word.rb:12:in `open'
    from suggest-word.rb:12:in `<main>'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

The corresponding 17th line is this implementation

```
doc = REXML::Document.new(open(url).read.encode("UTF-8"))
```

It works fine in the local environment for reference

Comment: Your program makes two HTTP requests, a GET then a POST. Which of these two requests receives the 400 response? Please include more of the stack trace.

Comment: thanks comment,

I add error occur line please look code
this program post keyword later get value


It seems that this error occurred during post

thanks

Comment: Try to `rescue` the `OpenURI::HTTPError` and `inspect` the error to see if it has any more information.

Comment: sorry i misstake select code.
change problem code show you